# How do I show the day of the week in CakePHP date?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I would like to have CakePHP default to show the day of the week for Date fields like `Monday, May 18, 2015`. What format string would I have to give to the `setToStringFormat` function and where do these formats come from? They don't seem to follow the [PHP date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Example:

```
Time::setToStringFormat('MMMM d, YYYY');
// Formats like: May 18, 2015
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the format you are looking for you can use simply:

```
Time::toFormattedDateString();
```

Also check http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ for more details as Cake use carbon at the moment for time

Comment: Ahh Carbon, thats it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. That carbon saved me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
// called via TimeHelper
echo $this->Time->format('2011-08-22', '%B %e, %Y');
```

[Detail Link URL](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#TimeHelper%3A%3Aformat).